# Serializing object from SQL to JSON with loops very slow

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask and SQLAlchemy and when I serialized a nested relation it is extremely slow. Here are the models I have

```
class attributes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attributes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    URL = Column(Text)
    Gender = Column(String(20))
    SAT =Column(String(10))
    ACT = Column(String(10))
    major =db.relationship('Major',backref = 'attributes', lazy="joined")
```

When serializing the "major" it is extremely slow. Here is the model for major:

```
class Major(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    majorlist = Column(String(20))
    Attributeid = Column(Integer, db.ForeignKey('attributes.id'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<major "{self.title}">'
```

I have tried serializing "major" like so

```
@app.route('/api/Majors', methods = ['GET'])
def major():
        major = db.session.query(attributes).all()
        majors = {}
        for row in major:
            majors[row.id] = []
            [majors[maj.Attributeid].append(maj.majorlist) for maj in row.major]
        return jsonify(majors)
```

I know that it is slow because of the nested loops but I am unsure of how else to optimize it. The result I want is:

```
{"1":[majorlist_1, majorlist_2],"2":[majorlist_1, majorlist_2],"3":[majorlist_1],"4":[majorlist_1,],"5":[majorlist_1, majorlist_2, majorlist_3] ...}
```

There will be around 1400 entries with each entry having a list of about 1-3 elements. The size of is only 7.1kb but the request is take almost 30 seconds!

I am pretty sure it is a problem with how I serialized it as the other attributes are fairly quick but I am not sure of another approach which would yield the result I am looking for.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Try reading it into data frame and as pd.read_sql() and then data frame to JSON no loop required.

Comment: It takes less than two seconds for me - are you querying over a network?  What database are you using?